# Bulk Insert, problema con campo sin doble comilla

Tags: sql-server

Estoy usando Bulk Insert para llenar una tabla con datos de un csv, pero hay dos campos que en el csv no están entrecomillados, y no llega a cargarlos, lo cual me parece raro porque no tiene coma ni nada que pueda ser problemático. Me explico:

Mi tabla tiene solamente campos varchar:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[states](
[id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_states_name] DEFAULT ('North Carolina'),
[abbreviation] [varchar](2) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_states_abbr] DEFAULT ('NC'),
[state_bird] [varchar](50) NULL,
[state_flower] [varchar](50) NULL,
[state_tree] [varchar](50) NULL,
[state_fish] [varchar](100) NULL,
[area_codes] [varchar](200) NULL,
[latitude] [varchar](12) NULL,
[longitude] [varchar](12) NULL,
[time_zones] [varchar](200) NULL,
[capital] [varchar](50) NULL,
[largest_city] [varchar](50) NULL,
[region] [varchar](50) NULL,
[lowest_elevation] [varchar](20) NULL,
[highest_elevation] [varchar](20) NULL,
[mean_elevation] [varchar](20) NULL,
[total_area_in_miles] [varchar](20) NULL,
[land_area_in_miles] [varchar](20) NULL,
[water_area_in_miles] [varchar](20) NULL,
[population] [varchar](20) NULL,
[population_1990] [varchar](20) NULL,
[population_2000] [varchar](20) NULL,
[population_2020] [varchar](20) NULL,
[10_year_change] [varchar](4) NULL,
[modified_by] [bigint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_states_modified_by] DEFAULT ((1)),
[modified_on] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_states_modified_on] DEFAULT (getdate()),
[created_by] [bigint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_states_created_by] DEFAULT ((1)),
[created_on] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_states_created_on] DEFAULT (getdate()),
CONSTRAINT [PK_states] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Como tengo al inicio el campo identity, y hay varios campos que no existen en el csv y se cargan con default, yo cree una vista para hacer la carga, luego como tenía problemas he ido probando eliminando columnas del csv y del view, para ver cuales son las que me están dando problemas, y me he quedado con este caso:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_states3] 
AS
SELECT [name], [abbreviation], [state_bird], [state_flower],[state_tree],[state_fish],[area_codes]  , [latitude], [longitude]
FROM [dbo].[states];
GO

BULK INSERT [v_states3]
FROM 'D:\Users\Pilar\Downloads\states1.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR='\n',
BATCHSIZE=250000,
MAXERRORS=2);
```

cuando cargo hasta la columna area_codes funciona bien, pero me da problemas con latitud y longitud. El csv es como sigue:

```
Alabama,AL,Yellowhammer,Camellia,Southern Pine,Tarpon,"205, 251, 256, 334, 938",32.31823,-86.902298
Alaska,AK,Willow Ptarmigan,Forget-me-not,Sitka Spruce,Largemouth Bass,907,66.160507,-153.369141
```

como pueden ver solo aparecen comillas en el campo area_codes cuando hay más de uno, porque están separados por comas y si no tienes las doblecomillas no podría leerlo bien, eso está funcionando bien, pero no me carga los dos que vienen después, que tienen punto (.), números y el signo menos, y debería cargarse en variables tipo varchar, realmente no entiendo porqué no lo hace.

Gracias por su ayuda

ACTUALIZACIÓN

el problema no es el tipo, lo modifiqué a decimal y tampoco funcionó, me dí cuenta que me mostraba error en algunas líneas pero no en todas, dejé una línea del csv que parece funcionaba y efectivamente funcionó, así que volví a ponerle varchar y esa única línea si funciona. Esto me hace pensar que el problema es algún caracter extraño, pero abro el archivo con Notepad++ y no encuentro nada raro.

Comment: Esos campos parecen ser numericos por lo que no irian como varchar

Comment: ok, pero yo puedo guardar números en un campo varchar, la duda es si necesito definir algo más para que el campo ingrese como varchar

Comment: he intentado cambiando el tipo de dato de ambos campos a decimal(10,7) y sigue dando error